# HASH+ASC compound index in YugabyteDB YSQL?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is the below index valid, and would it be appropriate for that use case?

The `CREATE INDEX` command (quite awesomely) allows you to specify whether you want the index to be based on hash (for point-lookups) or range. The `HASH | ASC | DESC` is attached to each `index_elem`(column that's indexed)...my reading of that tells me that it's possible to create an index where the first column is indexed via hash and the second is ranged? https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ysql/the-sql-language/statements/ddl_create_index/
For example:

```sql
CREATE INDEX task_queue_idx ON task_queue_entries (
  task_queue_id HASH,
  maturation_time ASC
) WHERE ....;
```

(Note that the `task_queue_id` is `HASH` and `maturation_time` is `ASC`)

The query pattern would be something like

```sql
SELECT * from task_queue_entries WHERE task_queue_id = 'foo' AND maturation_time <= NOW() FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT 1.
```

There'd be thousands of unique `task_queue_id`, and each entry in the `task_queue_entries` table could have a different maturation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is quite reasonable to have HASH+ASC compound (multi-column) index.. the first part being HASH (and give that you have 1000s of unique queue ids) makes sure your index doesn't have hotspots (during writes and reads).